# Cannot locate message in MessageSource

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am trying to get one simple spring application running but getting following exception:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No
>   message found under code 'label.firstname' for locale 'en_US'.

My contact.jsp file:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Spring 3 MVC Series - Contact Manager | viralpatel.net</title>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Contact Manager</h2>

<form:form method="post" action="add.html" commandName="contact">

    <table>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="firstname"><spring:message code="label.firstname"/></form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="firstname" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="lastname"><spring:message code="label.lastname"/></form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="lastname" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="email"><spring:message code="label.email"/></form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="email" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="telephone"><spring:message code="label.telephone"/></form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="telephone" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input type="submit" value="<spring:message code="label.addcontact"/>"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form:form>

<h3>Contacts</h3>
<c:if  test="${!empty contactList}">
<table class="data">
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Telephone</th>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
</tr>
<c:forEach items="${contactList}" var="contact">
    <tr>
        <td>${contact.lastname}, ${contact.firstname} </td>
        <td>${contact.email}</td>
        <td>${contact.telephone}</td>
        <td><a href="delete/${contact.id}">delete</a></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
</c:if>

</body>
</html>
```

My spring-servlet.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="net.viralpatel.contact" />

    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="WEB-INF/messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>



    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

<!--    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" -->
<!--        destroy-method="close" p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}" -->
<!--        p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}" p:password="${jdbc.password}" /> -->

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close" p:driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        p:url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ContactManager" p:username="root" p:password="12345" />


    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="configurationClass">
            <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

I am hitting url:

localhost:8080/MavenWeb-0.0.1/index

and my server stacktrace:

```
SEVERE: No message found under code 'label.firstname' for locale 'en_US'.
javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code 'label.firstname' for locale 'en_US'.
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.MessageTag.doStartTagInternal(MessageTag.java:184)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.contact_jsp._jspx_meth_spring_005fmessage_005f0(contact_jsp.java:252)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.contact_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005flabel_005f0(contact_jsp.java:219)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.contact_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(contact_jsp.java:138)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.contact_jsp._jspService(contact_jsp.java:91)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:419)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:471)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:329)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1047)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:817)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:563)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:403)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:301)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

**Steps to get issue resolved:**

1. Place messages_en.properties files in src/main/resource folder only
2. Make sure name of file is correct as messages_en.properties and not
   message_en.properties
3. When you do maven build using `mvn clean install`
   messages_en.properties file will appear in
   target/projectname/WEB-INF/classes/messages.properties
4. Check in spring-servlet.xml(name may vary) and use
       classpath:messages as basename in messageSource

and it should work as it resolved my issue.

```
<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>
```

Comment: any suggestions as to how can we fix the issue?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your `MessageSource` bean definition is a little confusing. Typically the basename is the prefix of the filename (minus .properties) you want to use for the message resolution, which Spring and the JDK `ResourceBundle` class will append the language and/or country abbreviation to.

```
<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="WEB-INF/message_en.properties/Message" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>
```

For example, if you intended to have resource files like `messages.properties`, `messages_es.properties`, `messages_de.properties` you would specify a basename of `WEB-INF/messages`.

What is the actual name of your message bundle file(s)?

Comment: i modified it to WEB-INF/messages but still am getting same issues

Comment: message_en.properties is the actual file name of my message bundle file

Comment: If the name of the file is `message_en.properties` (and it is in the WEB-INF directory) then you should have a basename of `WEB-INF/message`, not `WEB-INF/messages`. And to rule it out, are you sure this property exists in the file? Also I'm not 100% sure on resolving files in the WEB-INF directory, I typically just place these files on the classpath (i.e. src/main/resources in a Maven project which gets deployed to WEB-INF/classes)

Comment: is there anything else that needs to be checked or fixed in here?

Comment: 1) does the property actually exist in the file? 2) does the file actually exist in WEB-INF? 3) Do you get different behavior if the file is in WEB-INF/classes and the basename is `message` or `classpath:message`? etc

Comment: property exist in the file, in target folder, file does exist in WEB-INF, and yes behaviour changes when i use classpath:message then it is working and if i use `WEB-INF/messages` then it was not working.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, the solution was:

1. Place the **messages.properties** file in the source folder **src/main/resources**
2. Define the Bean as follow:

   ```
   <bean id="messageSource"
            class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
   <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
   <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
   ```

You see that I put in **property** the same name of the file **messages.properties** without **.properties**

that was the problem ^^

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the "resources" folder to "Web Deployment Assembly". After that replace "classpath:messages" to only "messages". The last change you need to make is clean your projects.

example:

```
<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="messages" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
</bean>
```

That will suffice. :)

Answer (score 1):

An important consideration is that, in order to auto reload, properties file should not be in the classpath. Servers usually cache the properties so if its in the classes folder, its not really effective. Per Spring docs, in case of classpath:messages, cachedSeconds other than -1 will not have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never. I had the same problem. Here is how I solved it.
My file name was :

### messages_**fr**.properties

for france because its a french Spring Tutotrial. But, i reside in The Nederlands. So i tried to rename it to

### messages_**nl**.properties

and it works. Not sure if this is a long term workaround but we ll see.

Answer (score 0):

To anybody else who will face the issue.

Besides all the answers, make sure you **let the .jsp file be processed by Spring Framework**. If .jsp is accessed directly, spring tags won't be processed, and you'll see the exact same error. Simply put, **expose the .jsps through the controllers**.

Answer (score -5):

I had the same problem but I simply left it as messages_properties and it solved the issue