# Error getting messageBundles from Controller

Tags: java, spring, message, applicationcontext

I am trying get a message locale from Controller but I obtain this error:

> `org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException`: Request processing failed; nested exception is `org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException` : No message found under code `'error.alias'` for locale `'es_ES'`.

In my Controller:

```
ApplicationContext context = MyContext.getApplicationContext();
        List errors = null;

        // Validar parametros        
        if (!Filter.onlyLetters(alias)) {
            errors.add(context.getMessage("error.alias", null, Locale.getDefault()));
        }
```

`MyContext.getApplicationContext()` obtain spring context from `MyApplicationContextAware` that implements `ApplicationContextAware`.

```
public class MyContext {

    private static ApplicationContext context;

    public static void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        context = applicationContext;
    }

    public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return context;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class MyApplicationContextAware implements ApplicationContextAware {

    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ctx) throws BeansException {
        MyContext.setApplicationContext(ctx);
    }
}
```

---

```
<bean id="myApplicationContextAware" class="...MyApplicationContextAware" />
```

"error.alias" exist in messages.properties and messages_es_ES.properties.

```
/WEB-INF/classes/messages.properties
/WEB-INF/classes/messages_es_ES.properties
```

---

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
<property name="basename">
    <value>messages</value>
</property>
```

Comment: in this post I found the solution to a similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6748939/cannot-locate-message-in-messagesource

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the full path as basename:

```
<property name="basename" value="WEB-INF/classes/messages"/>
```

EDIT: Does this happen whilst running your web application or during unit tests? I'm guessing it must a classpath issue, check if 'WEB-INF/classes' is on the classpath during the execution you are attempting.

Comment: Hi Adriaan and thanks for your help, but path is ok, in JSP I use messageSource together with JSTL fmt and works fine. Only I have problem into Controller.