# No message found under code 'application.title' for locale 'en_US'

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, resourcebundle

I am having my properties file in the src/main/resource folder.

- messages.properties
- messages_en.properties
- messages_en_US.properties

Below is the entry in my spring-servlet.xml file.

```
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<!-- Localization Settings -->
<beans:bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <beans:property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
    <beans:property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
    <beans:property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
    <beans:property name="cookieName" value="appLocaleCookie"></beans:property>
    <beans:property name="cookieMaxAge" value="3600"></beans:property>
</beans:bean>
<interceptors>
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <beans:property name="paramName" value="locale" />
    </beans:bean>
</interceptors>

<!-- Property place holder configuration -->
<beans:bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <beans:property name="location" value="classpath:config.properties" />
</beans:bean>
```

But I keep getting the following error

```
javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code 'application.title' for locale 'en_US'.
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.MessageTag.doEndTag(MessageTag.java:200)
    at org.apache.jsp.login_jsp._jspx_meth_spring_005fmessage_005f0(login_jsp.java:224)
```

I had literally tried everything for the basename value with classpath, without classpath but nothing works.

Comment: Do you have messages_en.properties file in your classpath as well or just messages.properties file?

Comment: I have files named messages.properties, messages_en.properties, messages_en_US.properties

Comment: How you change the locale in jsp?

Comment: @RohitNagesh Try to change `<beans:property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />`  to `<beans:property name="basename" value="messages" />` remove classpath: and see if it works.

Comment: @Ashyboy Had already tried that. It didn't work either.

Comment: Have you tried this solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6748939/cannot-locate-message-in-messagesource

Comment: @vineethsivan tried the solutions in the link, but didn't work

Comment: What is the URL are you accessing? Also please post the project explorer view in question. Also can you try `SessionLocaleResolver` instead of `CookieLocaleResolver`. Copy paste the message resource file into WEB-INF folder and try.