# Error in POM.xml file help in out for new coder

Tags: rest, web-services, spring-mvc

SEVERE: Servlet [spring] in web application [/RestControllerExample] threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet

Spring MVC Framework and REST

Spring’s annotation based MVC framework simplifies the process of creating RESTful web services. The key difference between a traditional Spring MVC controller and the RESTful web service controller is the way the HTTP response body is created. While the traditional MVC controller relies on the View technology, the RESTful web service controller simply returns the object and the object data is written directly to the HTTP response as JSON/XML.  For a detailed description of creating RESTful web services using the Spring framework

`
web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
  id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
     <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>

            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>

        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


<context-param>
<param-name>AppliactionContext</param-name>
<param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

</web-app>`
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>RestControllerExample</groupId>
  <artifactId>RestControllerExample</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>


  <dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
   <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
   <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>


   <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
   <!-- Set this to the respective version -->
   <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-beans -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
      <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

     </dependencies>

</project>
```

spring-servlet.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Enable autowire -->
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example.spring" />

    </beans>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6734773/issue-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-web-servlet-dispat

Comment: still no able to solve

Comment: post, please, your web.xml and pom.xml, it is hard to say without code where you have a problem.

Comment: For starters stop mixing versions... Don't mix versions of a framework you are mixing 3.0.5, 3.1.0, 4.2.3, 5.0.2 and whatever `spring.version` is pointing to.

Comment: i have provided the required files

Comment: my spring version is 4.2.2

Comment: There many diplicate dependencies with different versions. Please choose one version - as you say 4.2.2, and remove all duplicate for spring-webmvc, spring-context, spring-core. Than try to clean, reimport maven dependencies and rebuild project. Check that in your external libraries no dependencies with different versions.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have a lot of duplicated dependecies in your pom file and the groupId in your pom file is different than the groupId in your spring-servlet.xml !

I think this pom configuration will work for you ,but you have to set one goupId for the two files so if your classes java are in this package com.example.spring use it as a groupId in the pom

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>com.example.spring</groupId>
      <artifactId>RestControllerExample</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <packaging>war</packaging>
      <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
              <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
              <source>1.8</source>
              <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    <properties>
        <compiler.plugin.version>2.5.1</compiler.plugin.version>
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
        <servletapi.version>3.1.0</servletapi.version>
        <spring.version>4.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <jackson-version>2.4.3</jackson-version>
        <logback.version>1.1.3</logback.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.12</slf4j.version>
    </properties>
      <dependencies>
        <!-- SLF4J and Logback  -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring dependecies  -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- compile only, deployed container will provide this -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servletapi.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${jstl.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
         </dependencies>

    </project>
```